# VB.NET function that returns PDF?

Tags: vb.net, function, pdf, return

I'm trying to create a function that would return a PDF document. Something like this:

```
Function GetPDF(ByVal DirectoryPath as String) as PDF
   Return DirectoryPath
End Function
```

Any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: The question is what you wanna do with this file once you have this function.

Comment: What would you like to do? Convert files to PDF? Convert PDF to something else? Loading a PDF in memory and manipulate it? (hint, the last one is not easy. Best not to attempt it directly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do with it? Manipulate it? Serve it to a client?

Generally speaking you'd return a *Stream*...

```
Function GetPDF(ByVal filePath as String) as FileStream

    Return File.OpenRead(filePath);

End Function
```

or an *array of Bytes*...

```
Function GetPDF(ByVal filePath as String) as Byte()

    Return File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

End Function
```